# QT Dlls problem

Tags: qt, dll, dynamic-linking

I have small problem with qt dlls. In visual studio 2008 project compile fine and everything works, but when I try to open application in debug folder without using visual I had errors, so I copy all needed dlls to this project, but after that I don't have any error, and nothing happens (window doesn't appear on screen).

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio you can add a binary reference to the Qt dll's and it will ensure they get copied to your build directory when you debug. You need to might use a [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure out what all the required dll's are.

Comment: and how to add this binary reference in vs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also copy from your Qt install folder the "platform" dll located at : platform\qwindows.dll

to your running folder.

(I forget if you need to copy "platform\windows.dll" or just "windows.dll")

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the cygwin toolkit to resolve dependencies as well (ldd).  Another option is to add the library path to your %PATH% environment variable

Comment: The OP is using VS, if you use Cygwin's `ldd`, you'll get a lot of different and conflicting information that will not help in finding dependencies for VS.

Comment: yeah that's true, it won't help if the goal is to find/resolve dependencies